# Android (constants)

Tags: java, android

I've checked the suggested solutions and can't find my answer. If the answer is out there, then I'm sorry for posting it again.

I'm consuming a wcf rest service.

In my test activity I do;

```
private final static String SERVICE_URI = "http://10.0.2.2/Service1.svc";
```

This will eventually be used in various activities.

So what I want to do is: `private final static String SERVICE_URI = [CONSTANT]`

so that if I need to re-point the service somewhere else, a single code update will result in dependent activities pointing to the correct location, allowing them to work, rather than having to update each activity.

So: how / where would I create such a constant in Android, and how would I reference it?

Many thanks any help.

Comment: do you really need that constant be "final"... because java compiler my interpret final line compilation constant ... so the actual value is replicated everywhere you use it ... they do not reference it... by removing final compilator will provide a reference to where you use it .... Don't know if is what you expect.

Comment: To be honest; I don't know. I should have said at the top that I'm a VB developer trying to dev an android app for the client's site and am learning as I go on...

Comment: So may be as suggest the answer of MisterSquonk is what you looking for ... Like localization or configuration context ... you define one code and load dynamical the resource and the resource is automatically chosen depending of your application context ... if device landscape  then "landscape" resource is taken if device is configure in "french" then french resources are taken etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you describe it sounds like you need to look at [String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).

You can access them from any component in your Android app at any time and they're effectively 'constant' at build time.

**EDIT** Just to expand on the use of resources...

...take a look at Dororo's answer. All resources (strings, images / drawables and even UI elements such as Buttons etc) are accessed using 'resource IDs'. Any resId, i.e. `R.blah` is an int representing the resource. As such, it needs to be fetched in the correct way.

With UI elements we use `findViewById(...)` and with strings we use `getString(...)` as in Dororo's example.

My point was that the strings are constant at build time so it isn't necessary to declare any variable as `final static` that represents a string resource as part of any class such as an `Activity` because you can access any string using the `Context.getString(...)` method as shown in the link.

Comment: I created a values/constants.xml which didn't work. So I added <string name="CONST_RestService">http://10.0.2.2/Service1.svc</string> to values/strings.xml but private final static String SERVICE_URI = R.string.CONST_RestService; returned the error 'cannot convert int to string'

Comment: Do a bit of reading about string resources - you can't use them quite like that, the reason `R.string.CONST_RestService` is an `int` is that it's an *identifier* that you can then use to look up the resource value. If you look at MisterSquonk's link, and look at the example for String you'll see an example showing you how to look up a string resource from code.

Comment: Thanks MisterSquonk and everyone else. So, I kept the string in string.xml and instead of assigning the value to a variable in the activity, I just put HttpGet request = new HttpGet(getString(R.string.CONST_RestService) + [rest of the address]. Now when I move to the production server I can just update that one string.

Answer (score 5):

The alternative to String Resources, you could do it the via creating Constants class and put your constant value there. This method is not exactly specific to Android, but have been a practice that is used by the Java community frequently.

```
public class Constants {
    public final static String SERVICE_URI = "http://10.0.2.2/Service1.svc";
}
```

And refer it in other Activity/classes as Constants.SERVICE_URI. If you use this approach, you can use it anywhere even when Context or Application is not available for you.

Comment: Continuing the Constants class you can then switch your final constants at build time with Ant: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/switching-android-configurations-using-constants-and-ant/

Answer (score 1):

When would you want to change this string?

If you want to change it dynamically without issuing updates to the program, you'll want to probably set it globally and then create functions to edit it which can be called whenever you wish to change the address.

If you're happy to only ever change it when the program is updated (which not all users will necessarily do remember) then you'll want to set it as a string resource or just set it globally and slap on `final`. To access the string from a String resource use:

```
context.getString(R.string.resource_name)
application.getString(R.string.resource_name)
```

To create a string resource, open /res/values/strings.xml and create a new string using:

```
<string name="resource_name">whatever web address here</string>
```